# ufw configuration in Ubuntu 9.04 vs 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ufw, 9.04

So I'm migrating servers and need to match the ufw rules on the old server running 9.04 to the new one running 14.04.

So on the 2nd column after typing `ufw status` where it says `ALLOW`, I'm noticing in 9.04 it just says the word ALLOW, and when attempting to set the same rules in 14.04 its saying `ALLOW IN`. So are these two the same? And also in 9.04, will the 2nd column explicitly say `ALLOW OUT` if it is an *outbound rule*?

I failed to find a manual for ufw in 9.04 to see if this might have been a change that was done between the two versions, or if I'm just missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

### Usage

You can check the man pages by typing

`man ufw`

The [wiki about **U**ncomplicated**F**ire**W**all](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UncomplicatedFirewall) explains all the features and everything you need is on the [ufw server guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/firewall.html).

Ufw is set to ***allow outgoing*** and ***deny incoming*** traffic, through the ***default policies***, so you have to selectively allow traffic in.

Being that said, `allow` allows all outgoing traffic by default, setting a rule with `allow`, it will allow all incoming traffic according to the rule unless specified otherwise. eg. `sudo ufw deny out 1:19/tcp` .

You can set specific rules by setting `allow`/`deny`/`reject`/`limit` to `in`/`out`/`both`.

### Information

1. List the available application profiles:

   - `sudo ufw app list`
2. To get info on an app:

   - `sudo ufw app info name-of-app`
3. Check your status:

   - `sudo ufw status verbose`
4. Check your numbered rules

   - `sudo ufw status numbered`
5. Disable and enable ufw to apply the changes:

   - `sudo ufw disable`
   - `sudo ufw enable`
6. Reset ufw:

   - `sudo ufw reset`

Comment: Can you provide a syntax example of the `allow` directive of your explanation "You can set specific rules by setting allow/deny/reject/limit to in/out/both." ? And `ufw status` output of such a rule? I am more concerned with the potential differences between 9.04 and 14.04's ufw.

Comment: You can find more examples [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-14-04) while [allow/deny/reject/limit is the policy and in/out/both is the direction](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ecJpf.png)